# Function that accepts a tuple and returns another tuple

Tags: c++, function, tuples, c++14, overloading

How do I write a function overload that takes a tuple of any size and returns another tuple of the same size where int becomes double (with 0.5 value added), char becomes string, and size_t becomes int (by becoming the opposite sign), and whatever other type changes we may want.  For example the function `foo` takes `tuple<int, char, size_t>` and returns `tuple<double, string, int>`, while it takes `tuple<size_t, char>` and returns `tuple<int, string>`.

Comment: *and size_t becomes int (by becoming the opposite sign)*.  `size_t` is not required to be an `int`.  On many (maybe all) 64 bit systems it will be a `long` or `long long`.  So do you want the signed version of `size_t`

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? What problems is it supposed to solve? What's your use-case? Perhaps you should read a little about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and rethink your question.

Comment: An interesting exercise (probably why I didn't downvote). But seeing as any *"how do I do this from scratch"* question is too broad, so is this one.

Comment: @NathanOlver   That is just an example, which I tried to keep simple to get the main idea across.

Comment: The main idea being you want us to write a non-trivial piece of code for you, with extension points, for free?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

Step 1 - declare the concept of a converter:

```
template<class From>
struct converter;
```

Step 2 - define some specialisations of it. These spell out the conversion rules.

```
template<> struct converter<int>
{
    template<class Arg>
    auto operator()(Arg&& arg) const {
        return std::size_t(arg);
    }
};

template<> struct converter<char>
{
    template<class Arg>
    auto operator()(Arg&& arg) const {
        return std::string(1, arg);
    }
};

template<> struct converter<std::size_t>
{
    template<class Arg>
    auto operator()(Arg&& arg) const {
        using int_type = long long;
        auto result = int_type(arg);
        return -result;
    }
};
```

Step 3 - write a transform function in terms of an input tuple, a sequence of indecies and a converter for the type at each index in the input tuple (this one's a bit nasty):

```
template<class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
auto convert_impl(Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using tuple_type = std::decay_t<Tuple>;

    return std::make_tuple(converter<std::tuple_element_t<Is, tuple_type>>()(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))...);
}
```

Step 4 - provide an easy-to-use interface:

```
template<class Tuple>
auto convert(Tuple&& t)
{
    using tuple_type = std::decay_t<Tuple>;
    return convert_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(t), 
                        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<tuple_type>::value>());
}
```

Step 5 - write a test:

```
int main()
{
    auto t = convert(std::make_tuple(int(1), char('a'), std::size_t(6)));   
}
```

This solution also features perfect forwarding as a bonus.

Comment: It may have a bonus, but it doesn't meet the C++11 requirement as tagged by the OP. Still, nice showcasing of C++14, and I hope the OP just mistagged.

Comment: Changed my tag to C++14.

Comment: Well, now that the bulls-eye has been drawn around the arrow. +1

Comment: @StoryTeller haha thanks. Does anyone actually use c++11 any more?

Comment: @RichardHodges - Plenty of people. Some shops *just* finished adoption.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but the following solution isn't c++11 but c++14 (can be modified for c++11 but isn't trivial)

First of all you need a template function to (not)convert generic values (the ones you don't want modify)

```
template <typename T>
T conv (T const & t)
 { return t; }
```

Next you need the conversion you asked

```
double conv (int const & i)
 { return i + 0.5; }

std::string conv (char const & c)
 { return { c }; }

int conv (std::size_t const & s)
 { return -s ; }
```

At this point (using an helper function that receive a list of index for the types of the tuple), using the c++14 return `auto` type facility, it's very simple

```
template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
auto convTH (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t,
             std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return std::make_tuple( conv(std::get<Is>(t))... ); }

template <typename ... Ts>
auto convT (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t)
 { return convTH(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}); }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T conv (T const & t)
 { return t; }

double conv (int const & i)
 { return i + 0.5; }

std::string conv (char const & c)
 { return { c }; }

int conv (std::size_t const & s)
 { return -s ; }

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
auto convTH (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t,
             std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return std::make_tuple( conv(std::get<Is>(t))... ); }

template <typename ... Ts>
auto convT (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t)
 { return convTH(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}); }


int main ()
 {
   std::tuple<long, int, char, std::size_t, unsigned long long>
      t0 = { 0L, 1, '2', 3U, 4ULL };

   auto t1 = convT(t0);

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(t1),
      std::tuple<long, double, std::string, int, unsigned long long>>{}, "!");

   std::cout << "0) " << std::get<0U>(t1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "1) " << std::get<1U>(t1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "2) " << std::get<2U>(t1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "3) " << std::get<3U>(t1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "4) " << std::get<4U>(t1) << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C++11 solution for the return type, so that `auto` need not be used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, typename Map> struct FindCounterpartType;

template <typename T, template <typename...> class M, template <typename, typename> class P, typename U, typename... Pairs>
struct FindCounterpartType<T, M<P<T,U>, Pairs...>> {
    using type = U;
};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class M, typename Pair, typename... Pairs>
struct FindCounterpartType<T, M<Pair, Pairs...>> : FindCounterpartType<T, M<Pairs...>> {};

template <typename Pack, typename Map, typename Output> struct ChangeTypesHelper;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Output, typename Map>
struct ChangeTypesHelper<P<>, std::tuple<Output...>, Map> {
    using type = P<Output...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Map>
struct ChangeTypesHelper<P<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<Output...>, Map> : ChangeTypesHelper<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<Output..., typename FindCounterpartType<First, Map>::type>, Map> {};

template <typename Pack, typename Map>
struct ChangeTypes : ChangeTypesHelper<Pack, std::tuple<>, Map> {};

// Testing
template <typename...> struct M;
template <typename...> struct Pack;
template <typename, typename> struct P;

using Map = M< P<int, std::string>, P<char, std::size_t>, P<double, bool> >;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<
        ChangeTypes<std::tuple<int, char, double>, Map>::type, 
        std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, bool>
    >::value << '\n';

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        ChangeTypes<Pack<char, double, double, int, int, int, char>, Map>::type, 
        Pack<std::size_t, bool, bool, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::size_t>
    >::value << '\n';

    std::cin.get();
}
```